Error while require shlink-ip-geolocation
I wanted to require shlink-ip-geolocation to my instace but when I execute composer require shlinkio/shlink-ip-geolocation as given I get this error. I'm not trusted with php so I don't know how to solve this. I'm on Debian 12.
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - shlinkio/shlink-ip-geolocation[v3.5.0, v4.0.0] require geoip2/geoip2 ^3.0 -> satisfiable by geoip2/geoip2[v3.0.0].
    - shlinkio/shlink-ip-geolocation v3.4.0 requires geoip2/geoip2 ^3.0 || ^2.13 -> satisfiable by geoip2/geoip2[v2.13.0, v3.0.0].
    - shlinkio/shlink-ip-geolocation[v3.1.0, ..., v3.3.0] require geoip2/geoip2 ^2.13 -> satisfiable by geoip2/geoip2[v2.13.0].
    - shlinkio/shlink-ip-geolocation[v2.0.0, ..., v2.2.0, v3.0.0] require geoip2/geoip2 ^2.11 -> satisfiable by geoip2/geoip2[v2.11.0, ..., v2.13.0].
    - shlinkio/shlink-ip-geolocation v1.6.0 requires geoip2/geoip2 ^2.9 -> satisfiable by geoip2/geoip2[v2.9.0, ..., v2.13.0].
    - geoip2/geoip2[v2.11.0, ..., v2.13.0, v3.0.0] require maxmind/web-service-common ~0.8 -> satisfiable by maxmind/web-service-common[v0.8.0, v0.8.1, v0.9.0].
    - geoip2/geoip2 v2.10.0 requires maxmind/web-service-common ~0.6 -> satisfiable by maxmind/web-service-common[v0.6.0, ..., v0.9.0].
    - geoip2/geoip2 v2.9.0 requires maxmind/web-service-common ~0.5 -> satisfiable by maxmind/web-service-common[v0.5.0, ..., v0.9.0].
    - shlinkio/shlink-ip-geolocation[v1.0.0, ..., v1.2.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.3.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - shlinkio/shlink-ip-geolocation[v1.3.0, ..., v1.5.0] require php ^7.4 -> your php version (8.3.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - maxmind/web-service-common[v0.5.0, ..., v0.9.0] require ext-curl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's curl extension.
    - Root composer.json requires shlinkio/shlink-ip-geolocation * -> satisfiable by shlinkio/shlink-ip-geolocation[v1.0.0, ..., v1.6.0, v2.0.0, v2.1.0, v2.2.0, v3.0.0, ..., v3.5.0, v4.0.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-curl` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require shlinkio/shlink-ip-geolocation:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require shlinkio/shlink-ip-geolocation:^2.1" if you know which you need.


I tried to add the extensions into the .ini files as seen here.


You need the PHP cURL extension. On nix's you probably have to install that extension seperately into you PHP This may help with that



This could also help with you PHP version issues

